# Meteor 1.2 mobile app flashing when running on device

Tags: android, meteor, adb

I created a new app with the following steps:

```
$ meteor create newapp
$ cd newapp
$ meteor add-platform android
```

Set up an Android Device for debugging (Galaxy Nexus, Android v4.2.1),

Attached it to my machine (Mac OS X 10.10.5) via USB and confirmed it shows up using the `adb devices` Terminal command.

Running `meteor run android-device` worked and started the default 'Welcome to Meteor!' app on localhost:3000 and deployed the app on the Android phone.

On the desktop via Chrome, the app is fine.  On the phone, the app shows up, stays for a couple of seconds, disappears, shows up again, disappears.  I can't interact with the app and the app does not update (i.e. when I click the button on the desktop, it should up the count on the phone).

Anyone else seen this behavior before?  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you feel this might be a bug, I'd [report it](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues). Meteor 1.2 is fresh, and I'm sure there will be issues. People reporting these issues will help make the new release more stable, more quickly!

Comment: Seems like it had to do with Iron-Router not having routes setup on a fresh project.  The Iron-Router text appeared on the web, not on the phone.  Once I added some routes, the Android App and web app were in sync and working properly.